# Partial View: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I know there are numerous posts already about this but i couldn't seem to fix the error.

I am getting the above error (Title) in my Partial View which i believe means i have an infinite loop but i am not sure why this is happening. Please see below:

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult UserTable()
        {
            manager = new Manager();
            var data = manager.GetAllUsers();
            var userDetails = from u in data
                              select new UserDetail
                              {
                                  UserID = u.Id,
                                  Username = u.Name,
                                  UserLogin = u.Login,
                                  FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                  Surname = u.Surname,
                                  Email = u.Email,
                                  Active = Convert.ToInt32(u.Active),
                                  RightID = u.RightsId,
                                  GroupID = u.GroupsId,
                              };
            return View(userDetails.ToList());
        }
```

**UserTable (PartialView)**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.UserDetail>
@Html.Action("UserTable")
<br />
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                //Table Headers
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    //Various @Html.DisplayFor()
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Index (View)**

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("UserTable");}
```

If you want me to clarify anything or you want any further details please do not hesitate to ask.
Thank you in advance.

P.S The error is occuring in the UserTable Method.

Comment: You are trying to render UserTable view from itself by `@Html.Action("UserTable")`. Infinite recursion. Is it a typo or is it made for certain purpose?

Comment: What is `@Html.Action("UserTable")`? You need to show you view for that - the mos common cause is you have a `Html.Action()` or `Html.Partial()` with in turn call itself creating an endless loop.

Comment: Hi Guys, I had a meeting so haven't seen this until now, I used @Html.Action because if I don't then the User Table returns `null` as the User Table Method isn't being executed for some reason, hense the @Html.Action, any suggestions would be welcome. @AlexanderKozlov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem with the help of the hints from Stephen and Alexander in the comments. For me if I used Render Partial it didn't execute the Method for each partial view therefore returning null which is why i tried the Html.Action, but this causes an infinite loop, however if I use Render Action then the solution will execute the Methods, Hope this helps anyone that has the same problem.